# Isometry (metric spaces)

Tags: real-analysis

Exercise: Let $a\in ℝ$. Show that the function $f(x)=x+a$ is an isometry from ℝ to ℝ.

Question: Can this be answered without an explicit distance function d(x,y) for the metric space (ℝ,d)? I need to show d(f(x),f(y)) = d(x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $d(\cdot, \cdot)=|\cdot - \cdot|$ because this is the common metric in $\mathbf R$. Then
$$d(f(x),f(y))=|x+a-(y+a)|=|x-y|=d(x,y) \qquad \forall x,y\in \mathbf R$$
what shows that $f$ is an isometric.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different metric, $f$ might not be an isometry.